# How to turn methods into functions?

Tags: d

I have written a small helper function to emulate C++'s template expansion syntax.

```d
static template unpack(alias f){
  pragma(inline)
  auto into(alias target, Args...)(ref Args args){
    import std.conv;
    enum s = `target(`~iota(Args.length).map!(i=>text(`f(args[`,i,`])`)).join(",")~`)`;
    return mixin(s);
  }
  auto into(alias target, Args...)(Args args){
    return into!(target)(args);
  }
}
```

It can be used like this

```d
auto intTuple = unpack!(i => i * 10).into!(tuple)(1,2,3);
//Tuple!(int, int, int)(10, 20, 30)
```

This works as expected but I run into some issues if I need call a method that returns a ref.

```d
void test1(T)(ref T t){
  writeln(t);
}
Array!int ai = [1,2,3,4];
unpack!(r => r.front()).into!(test1)(ai[]);
```

This should roughly translate to `test1(ai[].front());`. But it doesn't compile because it seems that the lambda syntax can't handle ref return values.

So this fix this I would need to create a helper function

```d
ref auto cfront(T)(ref T t){
  return t.front();
}

unpack!(cfront).into!(test1)(ai[]);
```

Is there a way to express

```d
ref auto cfront(T)(ref T t){
  return t.front();
}
```

as a lambda function?

Or can I somehow turn the `.front()` method into a standalone function with the help of UFCS?

Comment: The helper function might be the best you can do...